# Changing initial zoom of InAppBrowser for iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Is there a way to scale the inital web view of InAppBrowser to a certain zoom percentage in Objective C for iOS development with the Ionic Framework? I was able to do it in the InAppBrowser.java class for Android with this line of code:

```
 inAppWebView.setInitialScale((int)(60 * inAppWebView.getScale()));
```

Here is the documentation for InAppBrowser.java (this line of code is added after line 897):
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the **viewport meta tag**? It should set the initial zoom for all platforms according to its values as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Comment: I think that is already set when I first created the project, I was wondering if there was a way to set the zoom of a web page to like what I did in that line of code for android for specifically one webpage. The initial view of the webpage is very zoomed out to fit the whole page, but should be zoomed in to make it easier to read, while the others that use InAppBrowser fit perfectly. I am just trying to copy that line of code from Android into iOS InAppBrowser plugin using Objective C